# Filter groups in dplyr that exclusively contain specific combinations of values

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a table like:

```
  id value
1  1     a
2  2     a
3  2     b
4  2     c
5  3     c
```

I would like to filter for:

a) the ids that only have value a, i.e. id 1.

b) the ids that contain a and b jointly, i.e. id 2.

Data:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,2,2,3), value = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"))
```

Answer (score 19):

Try

a)

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(all(value == "a"))
```

b)

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(all(c("a", "b") %in% value))
```

Comment: It throws me an error like:  In all(c("a", "a",  ... :
  coercing argument of type 'character' to logical

Comment: @VincenzoGrasso, something went wrong, I'll update in a minute

Comment: For (b) you could use `df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(any(value=="a") & any(value=="b"))`

Comment: @VincenzoGrasso, please see my update and check again

Comment: @SamDickson, thanks, that's another possibility, however, if you have a large number of values to look for, it might be a lot of typing

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach that can be used both for a) and b)

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(value) %>% summarize(value=paste(value,collapse="")) %>% filter(grepl("ab",value))
```

Result:

```
     id value
  (dbl) (chr)
1     2   abc
```

Hope this helps